# Android detect incoming call on background

Tags: android, android-permissions, phone-call, android-broadcastreceiver, incoming-call

I have problem with detecting incoming call. I have tried many tutorials, but it does not working. I am really not sure where is mistake.

I have added permission READ_PHONE_STATE, but still in Android Device Monitor see this warning (when calling from it):

```
Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.development.test.rejectcall/.background.IncomingCall requires android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)

Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.development.test.rejectcall/.background.IncomingCall requires android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.development.test.rejectcall">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".background.IncomingCall">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

IncomingCall.java

```
package com.development.test.rejectcall.background;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state call hook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("mujlog", "phoneNumber received");
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.development.test.rejectcall;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("mujlog", "Created");
        Toast.makeText(this, "started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share `compileSdk`, `targetSdk` part of your `build.gradle`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hQvAfP3q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use compileSdkVersion,targetSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion 23 or greater than that.Because in the API level 23 action PHONE_STATE in broadcast receiver gives permission denied
Use 21 or lower than that.below configuration works for me

compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
targetSdkVersion 21

Comment: When I changed it in 'Project structure' I am getting these errors: http://pastebin.com/3FrnqWTm

Comment: it is working now, how to handle android studio to not use  compileSdkVersion 23? It is automatically adding into project even if I have selected 21

Comment: Lowering the version is not the solution, as if someone wants to use it above 21, this solution won't be helpful.